# Python version 3.3 iterating over regex freezes

Tags: python, regex, freeze

I am trying to match a line in a text file using a regex, but every time I call pattern.finditer(line) the program freezes. Another part of the program passes a block of text to the formatLine method. The text is in the form:

```
line="8,6,14,32,42,4,4,4,3,5,3,3,4,2,2,2,1,2,3,2,1,3,4,2,3,10,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,1,2,1,2,4,"

def formatLine(line):
    print(line)
    print("----------")
    commas=len(line.split(","))
    timestamp="(\d+,){5}"
    q1="([1-5,]+){20}"
    q2="([1-5,]+)"
    q3="(true,|false,){10}"
    q4="(true,|false,){6}"
    q5="(true,|false,){20}"
    q6="([1-5,]+){5}"
    pattern=re.compile(timestamp+q1+q2+q4+q5)
    print("here")
    response=pattern.finditer(line)
    for ans in response:
        numPattern+=1
        #write to file for each instance of ans

    #these check that the file is valid
    print("here")
    #more code, omitted

formatLine(line)#call method here
```

The first and second print statements print correctly, but the word "here" is never printed. Anyone know why it freezes and/or what I can do to fix it?

Edit: After reading the comments I realized a better question would be: How can I improve the regex above to get the pattern below? I have just started python (yesterday) and have been reading the python regex tutorial repetitively.
Each value (true or false or digit is separated by a comma)..... the file I am pulling from is a CSV.

-Pattern I am trying to get:

5 digits (each digit is 0-60)

20 digits (each digit is 1-5)

36 true or false (may be in any arrangement of true or false)

5 digits (each digit is 1-5)

Comment: I suggest getting rid of the regex and just process each word from `line.split(',')` directly.

Comment: Yes, that would probably fix it, but I was more curious as to why it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: I think the regex machinery got confused trying to count exactly how many of each type of match there were.   Also, note `([1-5,]+){20}` -- the 20 is *characters* not *fields*.  It took me 10 years to get good at regular expressions :)

Comment: try to double escape `\\d` in the timestamp subpattern or use raw strings `r'(\d+,){5}'` (however your approach is strange).

Comment: I don't think it's actually frozen, I think it's just very, very, slow.

Comment: I think you mean numbers, not digits. "60" is not a digit. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression, particularly the `([1-5,]+){20}` part causes [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). It doesn't hang, it's just busy solving the puzzle: "get me digits repeated N times repeated 20 times". You might be better off replacing it with something like `([1-5]+,){20}`, although I don't think your approach is viable at all. Just split the string by commas and slice what you want from the list.

Per your update, this seems to be the right pattern:

```
pattern = r"""(?x)

    ([0-9], | [1-5][0-9], | 60,) {5}  # 5 numbers (each number is 0-60)

    ([1-5],) {20}          # 20 digits (each digit is 1-5)

    (true,|false,) {36}    # 36 true or false (may be in any arrangement of true or false)

    ([1-5],) {20}          # 20 digits (each digit is 1-5)

"""
```

Comment: my goal is to pull every instance of that pattern out a file that may have many unknown character or improperly formatted versions of that pattern. I am trying to avoid those.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Could you explain what the letter r and the three double quotes are used for? I realize that is Python syntax, but what do they do?

Comment: @Rilcon42: `r` is a "raw" string literal, triple quotes - a multiline string: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals

Comment: that makes sense. One final question when I replace pattern with what you suggested then run the code numPattern stays 0, meaning it found no matches. Is the for loop that updates numPattern incorrect for some reason?

Comment: @Rilcon42: the code in the question is incorrect (`numPattern` isn't initialized), but if we assume `numPattern=0` before the loop, yes, that means it didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is what the csv module is designed to do, no regex needed:

```
line="8,6,14,32,42,4,4,4,3,5,3,3,4,2,2,2,1,2,3,2,1,3,4,2,3,10,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,1,2,1,2,4"

from io import StringIO   # this allows the string to act like a file 
f=StringIO(line)          # -- just use a file

### cut here
import csv

reader=csv.reader(f)

for e in reader:
    # then just slice up the components:
    q1=e[0:5]        # ['8', '6', '14', '32', '42']
    q2=e[6:26]       # ['4', '4', '3', '5', '3', '3', '4', '2', '2', '2', '1', '2', '3', '2', '1', '3', '4', '2', '3', '10']
    q3=e[27:53]      # ['false', 'false', 'false', 'true', 'false', 'false', 'true', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false']
    q4=e[54:]        # ['2', '1', '2', '4']
```

You can then validate each section as desired.